# Are tempfile.TemporaryFile and tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile same in Python > 3

Tags: python

## Consider this

```
import tempfile

print(help(tempfile.TemporaryFile))
print(help(tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile))
```

The above 2 statements give same thing as the output, does both of them belong to same class NamedTemporaryFile

```
tp = tempfile.TemporaryFile(suffix="xyz.txt", prefix="abc",
                            dir="C:/bin/", mode='w',
                            buffering=-1, delete=False)
print(tp)
tp.close()

tp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix="pqr.txt", prefix="ghi",
                                 dir="C:/bin/", mode='w',
                                 buffering=-1, delete=False)
print(tp)
tp.close()
```

Also in the above code both these classes expect the same named/keyword arguments are both of them same in Python > 3???

Answer (score 2):

That depends on your platform. As I read the code in https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/eb126eddbd7542ac9d7cd2736116aee2e0bd03dd/Lib/tempfile.py#L560

```
if _os.name != 'posix' or _os.sys.platform == 'cygwin':
    # On non-POSIX and Cygwin systems, assume that we cannot unlink a file
    # while it is open.
    TemporaryFile = NamedTemporaryFile
```

For non posix (linux, etc) environments or cygwin these methods are the same.

Comment: Thanks @redimp, iam using windows, os.name is nt for me and os.sys.platform is win32

Comment: Then the answer is: Yes. These methods are the same.